# What is needed for minimalistic ONVIF video server?

Tags: c++, onvif

What is needed to make a software video encoder - ONVIF server compatibel?
Which services and methods at least should be implemented in it?

I don't need the descovery services, there is also no PTZ capabilities available. 
I only want the ONVIF clients to access my encoded video stream per "WS"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the requirements for an NVT. These requirements are mandated by the Profile S specification, because you can claim conformancy to Profiles and **not** to a particular ONVIF version.

The Profile S mandatory and optional features are defined in the [Profile S Specification](http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/op/20984_11763r01ONVIF_Members-Profile_S_Specification.pdf).